# SQL 'insert into select' into existing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a simple insert into statement:

```
insert into Worker(WorkingPlace) 
    select WorkingPlace 
    from source.Worker;
```

I got this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Worker_ID', table 'Worker'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

(By the way `Worker.WorkingPlace` is a nullable column)

I'm very confused, because I'm just inserting data into the 'WorkingPlace' column, aren't I?

Comment: Yes, you are "just inserting data". Thereby you are creating new rows. Those new rows need a value for `Worker_ID`

Comment: *"I'm very confused, because I'm just inserting data into the 'WorkingPlace' column, aren't I?"* yes, and no. When you `INSERT` data into a table, an *entire* row is created; you can't have a row which only has *some* of the columns of the table. Any columns you omit from the `INSERT` will have the `DEFAULT` (or `IDENTITY`) value inserted, and if they have no `DEFAULT` or `IDENTITY` value, then the value `NULL` is inserted. As you have omitted `Worker_ID` and it appears it has no `DEFAULT` value and isn't defined as an `IDENTITY` then `NULL` is inserted.

Comment: It appears the column `Worker_ID` is defined as `NOT NULL` and as the column is defined as `NOT NULL` the `INSERT` fails, as you have effectively *tried* to `INSERT` the value `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into Worker(WorkingPlace) 
    select WorkingPlace 
    from source.Worker;
```

This will create as many new rows in table `Worker` as there are rows returned from the select.

So if your query returns 10 rows, then `10 new rows` will be inserted into table `Worker`

This means that any column in that table that is defined as `not null` must receive a value, either from your query, or get a default value when that is defined.

suppose your table looks like this

```
create table Worker (id int not null, WorkingPlace varchar(50) null, SomeValue int not null)
```

then you cannot insert a row like this

```
insert into Worker (WorkingPlace) values ('something')
```

This will fail because you have not provided a value for then column `id` that is defined as not null, and no value for the column `SomeValue` because that is also defined as not null

if your table looks like

```
create table Worker (id int primary key not null identity, WorkingPlace varchar(50) null, SomeValue int not null)
```

then the statement

```
insert into Worker (WorkingPlace) values ('something')
```

Will only fail because there is no value for the column `SomeValue`.
The column `id` will get its value from the `identity`

Solution:

```
insert into Worker (WorkingPlace, SomeValue) values ('something', 123)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
DECLARE @Worker TABLE (id int, 
                       WorkingPlace varchar(50), 
                       SomeValue varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @Worker(id,SomeValue)
SELECT w.id, w.wPlace, w.something
FROM [source].[Worker] AS w
```